How to authorize graph API for schema extensions using getAccessToken in Outlook Add-in (InteractionRequiredAuthError: invalid_grant: AADSTS65001)
I get the following error when making a post request for a schema extension with Office.auth.getAccesToken in an Outlook Web Add-in:

AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application

I have already granted admin consent and implemented API permissions for Application.ReadWrite.All (needed according to Graph Explorer). I also made sure to include this scope in the manifest.xml. The only API scope that is exposed is access_as_user. I have also tried setting forMSGraphAccess to true (which should cause the 13012 error but for some reason doesn't - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph#details-on-sso-with-an-outlook-add-in)
Request syntax:
fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
    contentType: "application/json",
    Authorization: 'Bearer' + token,
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    id: "owneddomain_test",
    description: "test",
    targetTypes: ["user"],
    owner: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    properties: [
        {
            name: "data",
            type: "String",
        },
    ],
}),

});
I am using the following resources for reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins?tabs=xmlmanifest#configure-the-add-in (for defining scopes)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups

Edit:
I have already tried the steps in AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <app-id>
